# PHP socket_connect if using SSL?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, ssl

I would like to send data from my **PHP server** to my **Socket.IO server running on NodeJS**.

Everything worked fine on localhost *(using http://)*

But now, that the server is running on the web with secured connection

`https://example.com` ... it doesn't work anymore.

---

The **Apache server** is running and is secured on **port** `443`

The **NodeJS/SocketIO server** is on **port** `1337`

---

## PHP

```
function sendData() {
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        $result = socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 1337);
        if(!$result) {
            return;
        }

        $data = Array();
        $data["test"] = "Hello";

        $bytes = socket_write($socket, json_encode(Array("do" => "sendSomeData", "data" => $data)));
        socket_close($socket);
}
```

## NodeJS

```
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/home/certificates/certkey.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/certificates/cert.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/home/certificates/chained.crt'),
}, app);

server.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('listening on *:1337');
});

server.on("connection", function(s) {

    if (s.remoteAddress == "::ffff:127.0.0.1") {
        // UNTIL THIS, EVERYTHING WORKS

        s.on('data', function(buf) {
            // BUT THIS WON'T GET CALLED
            // USING HTTPS

            var js = JSON.parse(buf);
            console.log("Received data")

            if (js.do == "sendSomeData") {
                console.log("Yeah, 'Hello' arrived!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work anymore", please. What does happen? What errors do you get?

Comment: @ceejayoz The connection is made between PHP and NodeJS, but the `s.on('data', function(buf) {` part does not execute, because it gets no data. So nothing happens, the server continues running.

Comment: I doubt the problem is related to SSL, it's probably a difference in configuration between localhost and the server. Maybe there's a firewall blocking the traffic.

Comment: PHP doesn't run any differently with SSL. Does it work on the with an HTTP connection instead of HTTPS to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question due to finding the solution:

So if the server is running on https, it does't receive any data.

Therefore I opened **another server** that is `http` on another port.

---

```
var httpServer = require('http').Server(app); // on http create server
httpServer.listen(1338);
```

**It works now perfectly.**